# ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: nlp, google-colaboratory, taco, mlmodel

I am running TACO model using miniconda in google colab. After all requirements installation, I got an error when I tried to install tokenizer

`Failed to build tokenizers ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

[I use the command: '!pip install tokenizers==0.11.3'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27OqM.png)

I've tried to change the gcc and g++ version of the notebook's environment and install wheel seperately but the problem is still there.
Do anyone have the solution for my problem. Thanks for your help.